# Augmented Reality Bearing/Heading/Azimuth confusion. (iphone ARKit code)

Tags: iphone, math, gis, augmented-reality

```
- (float)angleFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)first toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)second {

//first is origin

//second is point

float longitudinalDifference = second.longitude - first.longitude;
float latitudinalDifference = second.latitude - first.latitude;
float possibleAzimuth = (M_PI * .5f) - atan(latitudinalDifference / longitudinalDifference);

if (longitudinalDifference > 0)
{
    return possibleAzimuth;
}
else if (longitudinalDifference < 0)
{
   return possibleAzimuth + M_PI; 
} 
else if (latitudinalDifference < 0) 
{
       return M_PI; 
    }

    return 0.0f;
}
```

The code above (taken from the open source ARkit project) calculates an angle from a point of interest to a point of origin (the user location). Given the azimuth (heading) calculated in radians, in the AR app im building I can detect whether a point is within its view port using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)viewportContainsCoordinate:(ARCoordinate *)coordinate {

double centerAzimuth = self.centerCoordinate.azimuth;
double leftAzimuth = centerAzimuth - VIEWPORT_WIDTH_RADIANS / 2.0;

if (leftAzimuth < 0.0) {
    leftAzimuth = 2 * M_PI + leftAzimuth;
}

double rightAzimuth = centerAzimuth + VIEWPORT_WIDTH_RADIANS / 2.0;

if (rightAzimuth > 2 * M_PI) {
    rightAzimuth = rightAzimuth - 2 * M_PI;
}

BOOL result = (coordinate.azimuth > leftAzimuth && coordinate.azimuth < rightAzimuth); //THIS LINE

if(leftAzimuth > rightAzimuth) {
    result = (coordinate.azimuth < rightAzimuth || coordinate.azimuth > leftAzimuth);
}

double centerInclination = self.centerCoordinate.inclination;
double bottomInclination = centerInclination - VIEWPORT_HEIGHT_RADIANS / 2.0;
double topInclination = centerInclination + VIEWPORT_HEIGHT_RADIANS / 2.0;

//check the height.
result = result && (coordinate.inclination > bottomInclination && coordinate.inclination < topInclination);

//NSLog(@"coordinate: %@ result: %@", coordinate, result?@"YES":@"NO");

return result;
}
```

The problem is i dont understand fully how it works specifically at the line where it checks whether a coordinate (point of interest) azimuth (heading) is in the view port range between the left and right azimuth points of the origins heading.

So to give an example of my misunderstanding - in degrees, if the coordinate (point of interest) calculates a bearing to the origin of 90 degrees, and then the origin view port is facing it at its own bearing of 270 degrees to the coordinate,  this would mean the user is looking at the point, but i dont understand why the code still works as it checks whether the coordinate azimuth bearing is within the origins viewport which i assume would be e.g. 250 - (270) - 290 degrees. And obviously the coordinates azimuth bearing to the origin was 90 so it should be false.

Any help understanding whats really happening here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use a function like

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
```

so that you are more clear in accordance to degrees and radians.
Hope this will help you..